# Como saber se o código segue escrito nos padrões da HTML5?

Tags: html5

Como poderia realizar, além de aplicar os conhecimentos que aprendi e as informações das documentações disponíveis, uma verificação para saber se um código antigo escrito em uma versão html anterior foi atualizado corretamente ou ainda está utilizando elementos e/ou atributos obsoletos de versões anteriores da HTML5? Obrigada.

Comment: No começo eu usava o validador do W3C à risca, depois eu percebi que seguir os padrões cegamente não tem nada de realista (é igual "boas práticas", uma coisa que só existe no mundo do faz-de-conta). Fazer certo é importante. Fazer burocrático não. E fazer tudo "exatamente" como o validador manda, não é o certo. O validador é muito bom pra você pegar enganos, e coisas onde você fugiu do padrão por engano. Só não faz sentido almejar 100% de validação. Se o que não valida é decisão "pensada", tá ótimo. Desde que você saiba o motivo de ter feito diferente.

Comment: Eu costumo dizer: aprenda direitinho a fazer o certo, pra poder errar com sabedoria depois.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fpt.stackoverflow.com%2F

Comment: Legal seu comentário. Na verdade eu queria algo que me alerta-se quando estou desenvolvendo com atributos ou elementos obsoletos de versões anteriores do HTML5 por estar acostumada assim, deixando passar batido novos recursos e possibilidades que por si só trazem benefícios não só para mim, mas para o próximo e toda a comunidade que eventualmente também fará manutenção naquele mesmo código. Obrigada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou esse?

https://validator.w3.org/

Existem outros no Google...

Answer (score 2):

Esse aqui está linkado no website oficial do padrão HTML5:

https://html5.validator.nu/

https://whatwg.org/